# I am getting an error "Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized." when trying to deploy artifacts to nexus through jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus

I have my settings.xml file in 'u01/jenkins/.m2/'. Is this the place where i have to configure for nexus deployment? Please advice

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project jenktest: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact tulsa.jenkins.test:jenktest:pom:0.0.1-20170905.090435-1 from/to snapshots (http://myhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots): Failed to transfer file: http://myhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/tulsa/jenkins/test/jenktest/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/jenktest-0.0.1-20170905.090435-1.pom. Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project jenktest: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact tulsa.jenkins.test:jenktest:pom:0.0.1-20170905.090435-1 from/to snapshots (http://204.26.165.206:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots): Failed to transfer file: http://myhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/tulsa/jenkins/test/jenktest/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/jenktest-0.0.1-20170905.090435-1.pom. Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized.
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to have a `<distributionManagement/>` section in your `pom.xml` file. Something like this:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>my-releases</id>
        <name>my-releases</name>
        <url>http://your-repository-host:8081/nexus/content/repositories/my-releases/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>my-snapshots</id>
        <name>my-snapshots</name>
        <url>http://your-repository-host:8081/nexus/content/repositories/my-snapshots/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Then you also need to have something like this in your `settings.xml` file:

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>my-releases</id>
        <username>your-username</username>
        <password>your-password</password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>my-snapshots</id>
        <username>your-username</username>
        <password>your-password</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

Please, note that the `<id/>` sections in your `<distributionManagement/>` in your `pom.xml` should match those in your `<server/>` sections in your `settings.xml` file.

Also, your `settings.xml` file must (normally) reside under `~/.m2`, unless you have defined thes in Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

Your Maven settings file should go either in the folder that Maven is installed in (globally available for all users) or in the home folder of the user that is executing the Jenkins jobs in `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml`.

You can call `mvn -X | grep settings` to see where Maven is looking for the settings files.

Comment: I see the settings.xml file in jenkins job folder and i did configured settings.xml file with repos and users having deployment privilege , thogh im facing unauthorized access error ? what could be the possible reason ?Thanks

Comment: The settings.xml should NOT be in your jenkins job folder. It should be in `/home/[JENKINS_USERNAME]/.m2/settings.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

try to run deploy manually from the slave, if it's works make sure you are using the correct settings.xml by adding `-x` to your mvn command.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation that we solved; where we were getting a "401 unauthorized" during the "release" job.

While trying to debug it, we changed the jenkins/maven job from:

```
"clean release:clean release:prepare release:perform"
```

to

```
"clean deploy".
```

The "deploy" worked, so that gave us confidence in the general config/plumbing aspects of the job.  But the "release" was still failing; all other aspects of the job configuration were identical (since we were just inline changing the goal and options)

[image]

To make it more complicated, in our case we dont hardcode credentials in the settings.xml file.  Rather, those are injected by Jenkins at build/job time.

Add "NEXUS_USER" here.
[image]

Add "NEXUS_PASS" here.
[image]

Configure Jenkins/Maven to use your settings.xml file
[image]

Add this to your pom.xml (should be no surprise here)

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>com.xxx.repo_releases</id>
        <url>https://sonatype-nexus.xxx.com/releases/</url>
        <name>Internal releases repository</name>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>com.xxx.repo_snapshots</id>
        <url>https://sonatype-nexus.xxx.com/snapshots/</url>
        <name>Internal snapshots repository</name>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

From the settings.xml (this file is a peer to the pom.xml in our git repo)

```
<servers>
  <server>
    <id>com.xxx.repo_releases</id>
    <username>${env.NEXUS_USER}</username>
    <password>${env.NEXUS_PASS}</password>
  </server>
  <server>
    <id>com.xxx.repo_snapshots</id>
    <username>${env.NEXUS_USER}</username>
    <password>${env.NEXUS_PASS}</password>
  </server>
</servers>
```

SOLUTION: It turns out the problem was the with the "maven-release-plugin", and that it could not interpolate the ${NEXUS_USER} in the settings.xml file.  Once we bumped the version (from 2.1) to 2.5.3, it all worked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the encrypted password doesn't work, just replace with the plain text password and username.

Comment: if we remove encrypted password it is working.  Please let us know how to make it work with encrypted password